# How to update properties of an array of beans while iterating in jspx

Tags: arrays, spring, javabeans, jspx

The model returns a list of beans which are displayed in a table using `<c:forEach tag>`. Some properties are of type input, so the user can edit these inline (optional).

The question is how to set a corresponding `beanObject[by row index]` when user clicks on checkbox? If clicked, then the appropriate bean needs to be updated via AJAX, I think.

So, how can we do that?

Normal Master-Detail approach has way too many clicks, that is why I need "update-able" tables.

Controller:

```
return new ModelAndView("daily","daily", dailyListOfBeansRecords;
```

Jspx:

```
form submit...
...
<c:forEach var="week" items="${Daily}"  varStatus="loopIteratorValue">
    <tr class="${loopIteratorValue.index % 2 == 0 ? 'd4' : 'd3'}">
        <td><checkbox id="present" onchange="ProcessedUpdated(this,${loopIteratorValue.index})" value="${week.processed}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you totally misunderstand jsp. jsp(x) is executed on the server side. you need javascript to do client-side processing.